# k-subset with maximal variance

Tags: statistics, variance

I have two versions of the same question :

1-Given a list of  number (with possible duplicate ), how to find a k-subset (with possible duplicate)  that maximise the variance ? is there a more efficient way than the obvious "check-all-k-subset" ?

2-Given a set of number , how do i select from that set a list of k number that maximise the variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to ask this on some Maths forum somewhere.  Just a suggestion, you will get better answers there.  The coding will be easy once you understand the algorithm, which is what you seem to be asking here.

Comment: how can i transfer the question over there ? or i should repost it there ?